# Determining the quartile of an observation in R

Tags: r

I have a list with multiple observations and their scores, so when I look up the observation e.g.,

```
Var_1["obs_50"]
```

it gives me the score

```
obs_50 
   12
```

Is it possible to also know in which quartile the score of this particular observation lies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem that you have a named vector. You would need to calculate the interquartile breaks with quantile and then figure out where your observation was sitting. The `findInterval` function is useful for the second part.

```
findInterval(Var_1["obs_50"], quantile(Var_1, c(0, .25, .5, .75, 1) )
```

I did like the idea of defining an `ntile` function as mentioned by @epid10 in his now deleted dplyr answer.

```
 # edited to fix missing parens and to now correct ntile for max value: 
 ntile <- function (obs, var, n_breaks) {
         findInterval(obs, 
                      quantile(var, seq(0,1,length=n_breaks+1 ),
                      right.closed=TRUE)) }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cut` to discretize a vector, e.g.:

```
set.seed(11)
print(x <- rnorm(20))
## [1] -0.59103110  0.02659437 -1.51655310 -1.36265335  1.17848916 -0.93415132
## [7]  1.32360565  0.62491779 -0.04572296 -1.00412058 -0.82843324 -0.34835173
## [13] -1.53829340 -0.25556525 -1.14994503  0.01232697 -0.22296954  0.88777165
## [19] -0.59215528 -0.65571812
cut(x, breaks = quantile(x, seq(0, 1, by = 0.25)),
    include.lowest = TRUE, labels = FALSE)
## 2 4 1 1 4 2 4 4 3 1 2 3 1 3 1 3 3 4 2 2
```

If you don't want to discretize, you can also use `rank`:

```
rank(x) / length(x)
## [1] 0.50 0.80 0.10 0.15 0.95 0.30 1.00 0.85 0.70 0.25 0.35 0.55 0.05 0.60 0.20
## [16] 0.75 0.65 0.90 0.45 0.40
```